# table causing misalignment in two column layout

Tags: spacing, floats, two-column

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and I've run into a problem I'm not even sure how to Google. I'm using the two column document class `IEEEtran` for a scientific paper. However the text in the right hand column seems to be "pushed down" by the table in the left hand column. I've uploaded a screenshot to:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like the text in the right column to align with the top of the table in the left hand column.

It is very hard to reduce this problem into a small document as it only occurs when the text, image and tables appear in the order and position they are currently in. 
I'm not sure exactly what information you might need to help me diagnose the problem, but I can try to provide any additional information needed.

I use the following to insert the image at the top of the page:

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centerline{\subfloat[cap1]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{img/img1}\label{fig:label1}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[cap2]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{img/img2}\label{fig:label2}}}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:L}
\end{figure*}
```

The table code I use is:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{center}

    \begin{tabular}{ |p{20mm}|p{5mm}|p{5mm}|p{5mm}|p{4mm}|p{20mm}|}
        \cline{2-4}
         \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\bf A}  &  \multicolumn{2}{|l}{} \\
            \hline

            {\bf E} & {\bf R} & {\bf N} & {\bf A} & {\bf \#F} & {\bf \% L} \\
            \hline
            A & $51.35$ & $90.28$ & $70.82$ & - & $0$ \\ \hline
            B 1/1 & $67.05$ & $82.45$ & $74.75$ & $3$ & $25.88$ \\ \hline
            C 2/3 & $71.47$ & $79.84$ & $75.66$ & $2$ & $26.12$ \\ \hline
            D 3/5 & $64.54$ & $80.75$ & $72.64$ & $1$ & $27.56$ \\ \hline
            E & $72.17$ & $78.59$ & $75.38$ & $2$ & $100$ \\ \hline
            F &$72.12$ & $84.45$ & $78.28$ & - & $19.23$ \\ \hline
            G & $81.60$ & $83.54$ & $82.57$ & - & $100$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{c1}
    \label{tab:c1}

    \begin{tabular}{ |p{20mm}|p{5mm}|p{5mm}|p{5mm}|p{4mm}|p{20mm}|}
        \cline{2-4}
         \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\bf A}  &  \multicolumn{2}{|l}{} \\
            \hline

            {\bf E} & {\bf R} & {\bf N} & {\bf A} & {\bf \#F} & {\bf \% L} \\
            \hline
            A & $59.22$ & $69.21$ & $64.22$ & - & $0$ \\ \hline
            B 1/1 & $73.84$ & $72.53$ & $73.18$ & $2$ & $23.58$ \\ \hline
            C 2/3 & $71.05$ & $66.26$ & $68.66$ & $1$ & $14.09$ \\ \hline
            D 3/5 & $67.44$ & $76.05$ & $71.74$ & $0$ & $16.13$ \\ \hline
            E & $58.29$ & $71.44$ & $64.86$ & $0$ & $100$ \\ \hline
            F & $72.33$ & $69.88$ & $71.11$ & - & $20.24$ \\ \hline
            G & $78.08$ & $75.50$ & $76.79$ & - & $100$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{c2}
    \label{tab:c2}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

I've tried adjusting the table column widths but this does not fix the problem. I have also tried moving the table and image around in the document but have not managed to find a way to get the table and image to appear close to where they are referenced in the text and not cause the layout problem.

Any ideas on what I can try to do to fix this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Thanks for providing the code snippets as that helps to clarify what you are doing. But, it would be actually better to provide a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) including the `\documentclass` and the packages that you are including.

Comment: Hi Peter, the problem with this particular issue is that it only occurs when the text, image and tables appear in the order and position they are currently in. If I remove enough text the alignment issue does not occur. However this wouldn't be a great solution since I don't have all the text I need then :) 

I could probably provide the full .tex file if that'd be of use.

Comment: Yep that is a common issue, and posting the entire .tex file is not a good idea. What I would do is replace the figure with a box of the same size, and you can use the `lipsum` or `blindtext` package if you don't want to include your actual text.  That way your question can actually help others who might come here in the future with a similar problem.  This also helps the person answering as they can then see if the fix they recommended actually solves the issue.

Comment: Any update on this? Did the answers below help? If so you should accept the one that did. If not, please post a full [MWE that reproduces the problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).  If you solved it yourself, you should answer this question so that it will help others who encounter a similar problem in the future.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I had a tight paper deadline last week so I resorted to moving the table around, which "fixed" the problem. It isn't the most satisfying solution though. I can try to produce a MWE to see if it can be solved properly.

Answer (score 2):

Without a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces the problem, it is difficult to know exactly what is going wrong for you. However, perhaps this will help. The result of this is that the figure appears on the top of Page 2, followed by the table as per your screen capture, but the columns work for me. As far as I can tell, this is corresponds to the position of the figure/table where you have the issue.

[image]

If this does not directly help to solve your problem, perhaps you can use this as guide in an attempt to reproduce your exact issue.  Note that the `lipsum` package just for dummy text, and the `[demo]` option to `graphicx` package is used so that I can compile this without your actual figures.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Note: [demo] option used. Remove for actual used
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-9]% adjusted to get figure onto top of next page
\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centerline{\subfloat[cap1]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{img/img1}\label{fig:label1}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[cap2]{\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{img/img2}\label{fig:label2}}}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:L}
\end{figure*}
%
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{20mm}|p{5mm}|p{5mm}|p{5mm}|p{4mm}|p{20mm}|}
        \cline{2-4}
         \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\bf A}  &  \multicolumn{2}{|l}{} \\
            \hline

            {\bf E} & {\bf R} & {\bf N} & {\bf A} & {\bf \#F} & {\bf \% L} \\
            \hline
            A & $51.35$ & $90.28$ & $70.82$ & - & $0$ \\ \hline
            B 1/1 & $67.05$ & $82.45$ & $74.75$ & $3$ & $25.88$ \\ \hline
            C 2/3 & $71.47$ & $79.84$ & $75.66$ & $2$ & $26.12$ \\ \hline
            D 3/5 & $64.54$ & $80.75$ & $72.64$ & $1$ & $27.56$ \\ \hline
            E & $72.17$ & $78.59$ & $75.38$ & $2$ & $100$ \\ \hline
            F &$72.12$ & $84.45$ & $78.28$ & - & $19.23$ \\ \hline
            G & $81.60$ & $83.54$ & $82.57$ & - & $100$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{c1}
    \label{tab:c1}

    \begin{tabular}{ |p{20mm}|p{5mm}|p{5mm}|p{5mm}|p{4mm}|p{20mm}|}
        \cline{2-4}
         \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\bf A}  &  \multicolumn{2}{|l}{} \\
            \hline

            {\bf E} & {\bf R} & {\bf N} & {\bf A} & {\bf \#F} & {\bf \% L} \\
            \hline
            A & $59.22$ & $69.21$ & $64.22$ & - & $0$ \\ \hline
            B 1/1 & $73.84$ & $72.53$ & $73.18$ & $2$ & $23.58$ \\ \hline
            C 2/3 & $71.05$ & $66.26$ & $68.66$ & $1$ & $14.09$ \\ \hline
            D 3/5 & $67.44$ & $76.05$ & $71.74$ & $0$ & $16.13$ \\ \hline
            E & $58.29$ & $71.44$ & $64.86$ & $0$ & $100$ \\ \hline
            F & $72.33$ & $69.88$ & $71.11$ & - & $20.24$ \\ \hline
            G & $78.08$ & $75.50$ & $76.79$ & - & $100$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{c2}
    \label{tab:c2}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
%
\lipsum[1-8]% Add dummy text following table to ensure it is properly placed
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

put the tabulars into the `figure` environment and then use `captionof{table}{...}` instead of the `\caption` macro. It needs the package `caption` if you do not have it already installed.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean put the whole table inside figure environment for the images?

Comment: without the environment `table`, which is all in the `center` environment