# Figures and Tables 'push down' text in the right column

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

When I use the IEEE two-column latex template, sometimes the text in the right column does not start at the top, but gets 'pushed down'. This happens sometimes when adding figures or table. A similar problem was already discussed [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31338/table-causing-misalignment-in-two-column-layout/48936#48936) in this forum

My problem just occurs with specific text length and figure sizes. My usual solution is to vary those parameter until everything fits. Has anybody got a 'real' solution?

Here are example files which show the problem:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25824831/misalignment.tex

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25824831/IEEEtran.cls

Comment: I obtain different output when compiling `misalignment.tex` with *your* `ieeetran.cls` than with the [CTAN version of `ieeetran.cls`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran). Does using the CTAN version fix your problem? Did you change anything in *your* version of `ieeetran.cls`?

Comment: I did not modify the file. I git if from http://www.computer.org/portal/web/cscps/formatting

Answer (score 8):

Your file runs good for me. However, some facts must be noticed from your MWE.

- In your table you have used `\begin{center}` environment. This introduces some extra vertical place in the document. Use `\centering` instead.
- Do not leave a blank line before and after the `\figure` or `table` environment. Instead put a comment line like this. This will avoid extra vertical space as latex will put a separate paragraph.

  [image]
- In `figure` or `table` environment, it is usually better not to put the placeholder like `[!t]`. Instead put `[t]` to give latex some room to adjust the placement. To keep the sections and figures/tables together you can use

  `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`

so that they are placed within the respective sections. (use this package judiciously).

- (Anticipating your query) To balance the last page columns you can try `balance` package

  `\usepackage{balance}`

and somewhere in the first column of the last page, you say `\balance` to get columns balanced.

**Note:** If nothing works out and the problem persists, then you can avoid the `figure/table` environment (i.e., do not float them at all). Do

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

in your preamble and

```
{
\centering
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{images//user-code}
\captionof{figure}{caption}
\label{fig:user-code}
}
```

for figures and

```
{
\captionof{table}{caption}
\label{fig:user-code}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | p{1.2cm} | l | }
\hline
\textbf{-} & \textbf{-} & \textbf{-} \\ \hline \hline
- & - & - \\ \hline
- & - & - \\ \hline
- & - & - \\ \hline
- & - & - \\ \hline
- & - & - \\ \hline
- & - & - \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

for tables. Hope this will be useful.

[image]

The last page with balanced columns:

[image]

**Edit:** OK now I managed to get the error with the file using the given `ieeetran.cls`.

> The given `ieeetran.cls` is some how modified and is not compatible
>   with the package `fixltx2e`. Hence with the `ieeetran.cls`, `fixltx2e`
>   can not be used.

Given `ieeetran.cls` with  `fixltx2e` gives this output:

[image]

and without `fixltx2e` (i.e., `%\usepackage{fixltx2e}` the output is:

[image]

I do not know how the `ieeetran.cls` provided by OP is modified and why? And how it changes this behavior is a mystery to me.

Comment: Only the MWE worked for me too, but together with the `IEEEtran.cls` given above, I also get glitches. So it seems to be a modified version of the class. No idea where the problem comes from, though.

Comment: @StephanLehmke, I found the reason how it comes like that. But Why it comes like that, I could not figure out. May be one should look into the changes made to the `ieeetran.cls` file provided by the OP.

Comment: The main difference seems to be the implementation of a new option for "IEEE Computer Society conferencs (CPS)". But the changes are mostly margins, font sizes & such, nothing inherently suspect to have such an effect. So I assume this is just coincidence: a random configuration of floating material which happens to trigger this error (whatever it is).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers. Throwing out the `fixltx2e` package did it.

Comment: @Christopher Here to say thanks one will upvote (by clicking the uparrow button above left of the answer) and if the answer solved the problem, by accepting it (clicking the green check mark below arrows). You can do both upvoting and accepting. That is the style we follow here. (if the answer was useful you may consider clicking the green check mark so that for others who search for similar things it will be useful)

Answer (score 5):

I have found that when using the `stfloats` package with `ieeetran.cls` V1.8a/b I also get this error. When I remove the \include{stfloats} package, the error is resolved.

Comment: This fixed this problem with the Oxford Bioinformatics template for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by using the latest version of LaTeX or including `\usepackage{dblfloatfix}` in your preamble.